# MS Teams bot - how to download file that was uploaded in teams from nodejs code

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I'm using teams bot api.
We want to support images - an agent will upload images in teams bot conversation, and the image will be sent to our server and converted to base64 back to a user.

The request that my server gets:

> {"text":"send file","textFormat":"plain","attachments":[{"contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.teams.file.download.info","content":{"downloadUrl":"https://*-my.sharepoint.com/personal/*/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=2f***b&Translate=false&tempauth=*&ApiVersion=2.0","uniqueId":"*","fileType":"pdf"},"contentUrl":"https://*-my.sharepoint.com/personal/*/Documents/Microsoft
> Teams Chat
> Files/myFile.pdf","name":"myFile.pdf"},{"contentType":"text/html","content":"<p>send file</p>"}],"type":"message","timestamp":"2022-07-25T11:13:17.7731472Z"........}

This is my code:

```
if (message.attachments) {
   const file = message.attachments.find(a => a.contentType === "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.file.download.info");
   if (file) {
         require('request').get({uri: file.content.downloadUrl, encoding: null}, function (err, res, body) {
            if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
                const base64Data = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64'); 
            } else console.log(err ? err : "statusCode: " + res.statusCode);
        });          
   }}
```

But I'm getting "statusCode: 403".

From the docs it seems like the URL should work:

> content.downloadUrl is a pre-authenticated link to download the file.
> To fetch the contents of the file, send a GET request to the URL
> in content.downloadUrl. The URL is only valid for a few minutes, so
> you must fetch the file immediately.

Comment: Could you please share which sample you are referring for this?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT can you please take a look?

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/working-with-files-in-your-microsoft-teams-bot-preview/ba-p/199441 here the doc

Comment: @user2503775 - Can you please check if you have configured proper permissions to access the downloadURL because it needs authentication ?

Comment: Do I need a token based on BOT credentials, or with the credentials of the users that use the bot? @ChetanSharma-msft

Comment: From the docs it looks like the downloadUrl is public - preAuth. what is the tempAuth parameter (and it's value..) that exists in the downloadUrl?

Comment: @user2503775 - You are getting the error because of the access issue, so please try to pass the proper configuration while calling it.

Comment: what proper configuration should I put? token based on bot credentials didn't work. should I put user credentials (user who uploads the file) ?

Comment: @user2503775 - Can you please check with the user credentials once?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The downloadUrl really has to be public, the problem is that our nodejs code use sanitazion on each input for security -

```
expressSanitized.middleware({encoder: 'XSSEncode'})
```

The sanitazion added "&amd;" to the downloadUrl -

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/personal/****/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=5c****c344&amp;Translate=false&amp;tempauth=eyJ0e........AwMDAwMDAv
```

That's why I got 403....

I added unescape function to remove the & and now it works.